# Masonry Layout and Custom JQuery File is not working together

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, head

I have defined mansory in the head tag of my html as follows

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseURL}/assets/javascript/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
                $('.mediaListContainer').masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.mediaContainerMasonary'
                }).imagesLoaded(function() {
                    $('.mediaListContainer').masonry('reload');
                });;
            });
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseURL}/assets/javascript/index.js"></script>
```

I also have custom Jquery file, index.js. If I remove the masonry script then index.js works. Else it is not working?

Basically I want to have animation effect when the cursor is placed on my images.

Could you please help me with the solution?

Comment: Try to add it to the end instead of the head

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseURL}/assets/javascript/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseURL}/assets/javascript/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{$baseURL}/assets/javascript/index.js"></script>.

Comment: I tried adding it in the end. But if I have cdn links my index.js is not working

Comment: A link or a jsFiddle please.